# Can I use std::lower_bound on function calls instead iterators?

Tags: c++, algorithm, std, binary-search

Simple use case: I want to find with binary search the minimal index `i` for which `f(i)>=t`, where `t` is some threshold and `f` is a monotonically increasing function over integer values.

A simple way to go would be to just call this function on every possible input, save it to a container and then use `lower_bound`, this would be useful in a scenario where I want to do multiple searches on the same function with different thresholds.

However, in my scenario, function evaluations are runtime expensive and I have multiple different functions/lambdas on which I only perform a single binary search.

So I guess, what I need, is either a `lower_bound` function taking a function and a value range instead of start and end iterators, or I need a mechanism to hide the function calls inside an iterator structure. I know the first solution is easy to implement, but I hoped for a solution that would avoid implementing binary search from scratch.

To me, this seemed like a common use case but somehow I failed to find anything on this particular problem on the web. I'd appreciate any tips, tricks, and links.

**EDIT**

I found the two first provided solutions very intriguing. The given solution using the `comp` argument is very elegant, however I forget to mention a reason why this approach does not work for me. In addition to long runtimes for a single function evaluation I also have the problem of having a large search space (e.g. over `10**15` integers) which makes it impractical to allocate a dummy vector for this purpose. I do not know how it would work with the `boost` increment iterators but I need something to work with `std` only anyway.

The second solution using a custom iterator is quite verbose though. I tested it with the large number I mentioned (and changing the `int`s to `long long`s) but this seems to be also to slow. It seems that `lower_bound` actually calls the `operator++` several times to go from one location to the other, so the implementation of the `std::lower_bound` might already be the killer for my approach here (see below modified code example and output) and there is no way around a custom implementation (which I already have, no need here).

Thanks, however, for the insights, both answers showed me something new. And maybe someone can shine some more light on the points mentioned above, as I am definitely no expert on iterators or the implementation of `lower_bound`, maybe I used it wrong or it is something about the code example given by @idclev that makes it iterate this inefficiently through the numbers which I did not recognize.

**Modified code example**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

long long foo(long long i){ std::cout << "function evaluation:\t" << i << std::endl; return i;}

using function_type = long long(*)(long long);

template <function_type F>
struct fun_iterator {

    using difference_type = size_t;
    using value_type = long long;
    using pointer = int*;
    using reference = int&;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    static std::unordered_map<long long,long long> m;
    long long index;
    fun_iterator(long long index) : index(index) {}

    fun_iterator& operator++() {
        std::cout << "operator++:\t" << index << std::endl;
        ++index;
        return *this;
    }
    fun_iterator operator++(int x) {
        fun_iterator it = *this;
        ++index;
        return it;
    }
    int operator*() {
        auto it = m.find(index);
        if (it != m.end()) return it->second;
        auto res = F(index);
        m[index] = res;
        return res;
    }
    bool operator!=(const fun_iterator& other){
        return index != other.index;
    }
    bool operator==(const fun_iterator& other){
        return index == other.index;
    }
    bool operator<(const fun_iterator& other){
        return index < other.index;
    }
};

template <function_type F>
std::unordered_map<long long,long long> fun_iterator<F>::m;

template <function_type F>
std::pair<fun_iterator<F>,fun_iterator<F>> make_begin_and_end(long long begin,long long end){
    return {{begin},{end}};
}

int main() {
    auto x = make_begin_and_end<foo>(0,10L);
    auto it = std::lower_bound(x.first,x.second,4L);
    // auto x = make_begin_and_end<foo>(0,1000000000000L);
    // auto it = std::lower_bound(x.first,x.second,400000000000L);
    std::cout << it.index << std::endl;
}
```

and the output:

```
operator++: 0
operator++: 1
operator++: 2
operator++: 3
operator++: 4
operator++: 5
operator++: 6
operator++: 7
operator++: 8
operator++: 9
operator++: 0
operator++: 1
operator++: 2
operator++: 3
operator++: 4
function evaluation:    5
operator++: 0
operator++: 1
function evaluation:    2
operator++: 2
operator++: 3
function evaluation:    4
function evaluation:    3
operator++: 3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

As @KamilCuk suggested, write your own iterator, or alternatively

You can take any container of natural numbers (if you don't have ranges at hand, simply create an `std::vector<int>` and populate it with monotonically growing numbers — provided you at least know the boundaries of expected interval your expected value lies within). Next, `std::lower_bound` accepts a `comp` argument:

```cpp
std::vector<int> args(1000);
std::iota(args.begin(), args.end(), 0);
root = std::lower_bound(args.cbegin(), args.cend(), t,
        [](int x, int t){ return f(x) < t; });
```

(As a sanity check, check if `root` is `args`'s begin — then 0 can be higher than your desired root — or is `args`'s end — then the root is higher than the estimated right boundary.)

Comment: I would add that the vector can be filled with `std::iota` algorithm.

Comment: Instead of `std::vector`, you can employ [`boost::counting_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html): `std::lower_bound(boost::counting_iterator<int>(0), boost::counting_iterator<int>(1000), ...);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own iterator and to avoid unnessesary evaluations of the function, you can use memoization. The iterator can have a static map to cache results of function calls. To make iterators for different functions a different type, I parametrized the iterator on a function pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

double foo(int i){ return i;}

using function_type = double(*)(int);

template <function_type F>
struct fun_iterator {

    using difference_type = size_t;
    using value_type = int;
    using pointer = int*;
    using reference = int&;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    static std::unordered_map<int,double> m;
    int index;
    fun_iterator(int index) : index(index) {}

    fun_iterator& operator++() {
        ++index;
        return *this;
    }
    fun_iterator operator++(int x) { 
        fun_iterator it = *this;
        ++index;
        return it;
    }
    int operator*() { 
        auto it = m.find(index);
        if (it != m.end()) return it->second;
        auto res = F(index);
        m[index] = res;
        return res;
    }
    bool operator!=(const fun_iterator& other){
        return index != other.index;
    }
    bool operator==(const fun_iterator& other){
        return index == other.index;
    }
    bool operator<(const fun_iterator& other){
        return index < other.index;
    }
};

template <function_type F>
std::unordered_map<int,double> fun_iterator<F>::m;

template <function_type F>
std::pair<fun_iterator<F>,fun_iterator<F>> make_begin_and_end(int begin,int end){
    return {{begin},{end}};
}

int main() {
    auto x = make_begin_and_end<foo>(0,100);
    auto it = std::lower_bound(x.first,x.second,50);
    std::cout << it.index;
}
```

The map will be reused also for later instances of `fun_iterator` for the same function. And because it is parametrized on the function pointer, a `fun_iterator` for a different function uses a different map to store the results.